# Brew cleanup Error: Permission denied @ unlink_internal

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I met an error while doing "brew cleanup":

```
$ brew cleanup
Warning: Skipping opam: most recent version 2.0.3 not installed
Warning: Skipping python: most recent version 3.7.2_2 not installed
Warning: Skipping sqlite: most recent version 3.27.1 not installed
Error: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/.bin/in-install
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

PS: `brew link node` returns an error, though I don't know if it is related.

```
$ brew install node
Warning: node 11.9.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
Target /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

First fix permissions causing the error:

```
sudo chown -R "$(whoami)":admin /usr/local
```

---

On macOS Mojave, the `chown` command needs to be run on the specific directory, an example for the permissions issue in `/usr/local/lib` directory, this command would be

```
sudo chown -R "$(whoami)":admin /usr/local/lib
```

---

Then relink `node` with the `--force` option as directed:

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

Comment: The `chown` command returned `chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: @SoftTimur did you prefix it with `sudo` ?

Try first then on `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: `sudo chown -R "$(whoami)":admin /usr/local/lib` did not return error. Apparently, we could not do that on `/usr/local`.

Comment: Tested your solution now, as for @SoftTimur, sudo chown -R "$(whoami)":admin /usr/local return operation not permitted but also it seems brew not working anymore... /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/object/blank (LoadError)
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: **Caveat**: changing the ownership of `/usr/local` could have unexpected impact because not everything within `/usr/local` are related to Homebrew, one notable exception is **McAfee**, which would be broken by this change.

Comment: @ryenus That sounds ridiculous.

Comment: @hmedia1 I'd say thank you, as I should have pointed out explicitly that the key destructive bit is recursive chmod with the `-R` option. And it happened, e.g. https://www.unix.com/os-x-apple-/161764-sudo-chown-r-whoami-usr-local.html

Comment: @ryenus `/usr/local` is not a system folder on Mac, it's crazy for an app to be designed so poorly that it fails to run if `/usr/local` is owned by the user.  I have literally thousands of folders under `/usr/local`, and I have been using `chmod -R` on it for as long as I've had a mac (many years).  Not once have I had an issue because of that, and I have *many* development environments, tools, libraries, multiple versions of Python, and other system/user combinations.  I might even suggest that McAfee works better when it won't start.  Who has that on a Mac, anyway?

Comment: @hmedia1 Totally agreed with you. I was able to fix problem by running command only for "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/"

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
brew unlink node && brew link node
```